# Photoshop virtual appliance

Tags: virtualization

Is there a Photoshop virtual appliance?  I failed at Googling for one.

In other words, is there a pre-packaged virtual machine that is intended to simply run Photoshop scripts?

Lastly, is there a pay-per-use fully-hosted Photoshop script-running platform I can use on-demand?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Comment: How come you can post such a short answer and I can't? What's the trick?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Click the "edit" button.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual appliance as such does not exist yet. Each Photoshop installation requires it's own unique license.

To make large scale installations easier, you can use the [Adobe Provisioning Toolkit Enterprise Edition](http://blogs.adobe.com/oobe/tag/adobe-provisioning-toolkit-enterprise-edition).

Recently, Adobe announced the [Creative Cloud](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/9221146/Photoshop-goes-into-the-cloud-with-new-version-of-Adobe-Creative-Suite.html) service. This new service is based on a subscription model and will move some features of the software to the cloud. But for the foreseeable future, Photoshop remains an application that requires installation. So the Creative Cloud will probably not solve your problem either.